# Can't import DLL once it's been moved

Tags: .net, vb.net, dll, dllimport

I've written a class library in VB.NET which i want to be able to access from an external program (gINT).  gINT has a 'macro' like interface built on Sax Basic.

I've set "Register for COM interop" in Visual Studio>Project Properties>Compile tab.

From the gINT code interface, the DLL "built" by VS is visible, and can be 'imported' by gINT.

However, if i move the DLL (and .tlb etc) files to a different directory i get a "Bad Reference" error from gINT, and it can't fire up the DLL. I've tried referencing to a copy of the DLL built by the debugging compiler, as well as one distributed following publishing my project.

Don't really know what else to try.

Comment: Well, don't move it, change the Output Directory setting instead.  Sooner or later you are going to have to learn how to use Regasm.exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you've built the assembly using COM, and have probably registered the dll/assembly. You will need to register the assembly in the new location, or investigate using registration-free COM from the gINT side so that it doesn't have to be registered.

Comment: Sure, use regasm.exe. If you can't find the program, it should be available from the developer command prompt from Visual Studio.

Comment: Winner, thanks bro. "regasm /tlb myDLL.dll" at the developer command prompt did the trick